# Child element not inheriting parent's curved edges?

Tags: css, html, carousel, curve

I have a carousel at [my page](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com). I have both the parent element and the child element's edges curved but when you press "Next" or "Previous" and slide the carousel the child doesn't stay curved when moving. How can I prevent this?

```
.holder {
width:650px;
margin:200px auto;
overflow:hidden;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

#s7 #posts {
width: 620px; 
padding: 15px; 
color: #333; 
font-size: 14px; 
text-align:left; 
background:#EEE;
line-height:16px;
min-height:500px;
overflow:visible;
z-index:-1;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm willing to bet that it does stay curved, it's just a little to fast to see.  It doesn't *look* curved because you're seeing the middle of it while it's animating which, of course, is not curved (e.g. you're seeing the TOP of the box, not the top-left corner).

add the radius to the parent `div#s7` and you should be set.

Comment: I tested this by getting rid of the corners and adding them to the parent only and right before the page loads entirely the child obeys the parent element but when the page loads it fails to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're passing the `border-radius` CSS into the JavaScript, or rather, make sure JS/JQuery isn't removing it.

Using Firebug, I can see that there is no border-radius property assigned to all of the `<div>`s that are generated. Adding that attribute within your JS should remedy the problem.